# Request for tag synonym [the-struggle-for-catan] → [struggle-for-catan]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

In 2011, *The Struggle for Catan* was released as a spinoff game in the *Catan* series. In 2016, the game was re-released as simply *Struggle for Catan*. You can see the different versions [here on BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/91534/struggle-catan/versions).

Could we please create a tag synonym of [the-struggle-for-catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-struggle-for-catan) → [struggle-for-catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/struggle-for-catan)? That way, both game names are covered.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Thanks for doing this! Do you want to create an answer so that I can mark this question as accepted?